# Using Google 'Protocol Buffers' in Arduino

Tags: arduino, protocol-buffers, avr

Is it possible to make Google [Protocol Buffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) work in Arduino?

I have been trying for about a week and can't make it work, and I would like to know if it's even possible.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should fit on an Arduino:
https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb

Answer (score 4):

I've managed, after several attempts, to compile google protocol buffers for Arduino (using lite runtime), and still, the resulting code size was way over the 32k limit. So, for now, GPB isn't a viable option for Arduino projects. (maybe on Arduino Mega?)

I suggest you look at [MQTT](http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/) for a suitable replacement (I'll do that).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the link provided it says it has bindings for C++.  This is essentially what the arduino is programed in.  I see no reason why it wouldn't work.  If you were to post some details (the data object your trying to process and the C++ code the system generated) we might be able to help.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but I'm having troubles making the generated code compile. (It uses C++ standard library, not fully present in Arduino environment). I'm manually adding the libraries it needs though, but couldn't make it work yet :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a tutorial on using Protobuf on Arduino, you can check out my article: [A simple Arduino IoT example with Protobuf](https://embeddedproto.com/a-simple-arduino-iot-example-with-protobuf/). The code is available on [Github](https://github.com/Embedded-AMS/EmbeddedProto_Example_Arduino_Pro_WiFi_to_NodeJS).

The tutorial uses my library [Embedded Proto](https://embeddedproto.com). You have to copy the Embedded Proto to the Arduino library folder, and it will build. Full details in the tutorial.

If you have any questions, let me know.